# What should I use as Cognito's UserContextData => EncodedData?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

In all AWS Cognito SDKs in most functions you can pass an `UserContextData` parameter to feed Cognito's Advanced Security feature:

```
$result = $client->forgotPassword([
  'AnalyticsMetadata' => [
    'AnalyticsEndpointId' => '<string>',
  ],
  'ClientId' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
  'SecretHash' => '<string>',
  'UserContextData' => [  // <=================== THIS
    'EncodedData' => '<string>',
  ],
  'Username' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
]);
```

This field expects some `EncodedData`.

**What should I put in `UserContextData` and how do I "encode" it?**

When using an `Admin*` function like `AdminInitiateAuth` I can send unencoded fingerprinting data through `ContextData`:

```
$result = $client->adminInitiateAuth([
    [...]
    'ContextData' => [
        'EncodedData' => '<string>',
        'HttpHeaders' => [ // REQUIRED
            [
                'headerName' => '<string>',
                'headerValue' => '<string>',
            ],
            // ...
        ],
        'IpAddress' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
        'ServerName' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
        'ServerPath' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    ],
    [...]
]);
```

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-idp-2016-04-18.html#shape-usercontextdatatype) does not help:
[image]

Comment: Did you already find the answer?

Comment: @Ardian Nope :(

Comment: I found out there is something like this should be processed with HMAC sha256
https://pastebin.com/yM5dPr2k
I extracted from this SDK for javascript, on `getData` function:
https://amazon-cognito-assets.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/amazon-cognito-advanced-security-data.min.js

```
AmazonCognitoAdvancedSecurityData.getData('username', USER_POOL_ID , CLIENT_ID')
```

But still I don't have exact answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS provides an [opaque implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) for user context data.

`encodedData` is to be collected on device and not the server.

The Cognito [Javascript client SDK](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js/blob/v1.3.2/src/CognitoAuth.js#L759) exposes a method to achieve this. It is provided for in the [Amplify Android SDK](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/release_v2.16.8/aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognitoidentityprovider/CognitoUserPool.java#L537)

You can get transfer `encodedData` from client to server, then forward that in your request to Cognito.

Comment: This makes sense. But it also means that if I want this information in my PHP app, I need to load the javascript sdk client side just for this call... I'll accept your answer when close to the bounty end ;)

Comment: I think it will be bloated if we load the SDK just to call this one liner `AmazonCognitoAdvancedSecurityData.getData('username', USER_POOL_ID , CLIENT_ID')` as I mentioned on my previous comment. I'm looking something so we can compose that encoded data from the back-end, though. So no changes on the frontend except passing IP address, user agent, etc to the backend.

Comment: @Ardian this encoded data is used to fingerprint the user's device. So it makes sense to be called from the client. A "degraded" mode similar to the ContextData from Admin functions would be nice though.

Comment: I meant frontends (web, android and iOS app) without installing SDK on their own. They just send the required data such as IP address, UserAgent, OS version, etc. Backend will then compose all of those data as encoded data to be send to Cognito with Adaptive auth. Currently, if I compose the encoded data from the backend, Adaptive auth considers it as "Medium Risk" and I still don't know whether we can do the fingerprinting with raw data from the backend or not.

Comment: Until AWS describes what goes into the data mix and how it is encoded, this is playing a cat and mouse game reverse engineering the encoded data. They may be collecting more information than we know to fingerprint the device. There is also possibility of them composing a salted hash from the fingerprint information.

Comment: Yes true. I ended up using their SDK to get the `encodedData` thing, both from mobile and the web :-)

Comment: Hi @Ardian,

We have web application built using react and redux. How can I get `encodedData` in my web application. What package I have to install to use  `AmazonCognitoAdvancedSecurityData.getData('username', USER_POOL_ID , CLIENT_ID')`. Can you please provide any sample code.

Comment: Hi @samba 
I have implemented it by including this encoded data generator script https://amazon-cognito-assets.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/amazon-cognito-advanced-security-data.min.js . You can put on the login page and set the watcher on username field for username argument.

Comment: Hi @Ardian I just added encoded data generator script in my index.html page(I didn't included any other SDK) and called `AmazonCognitoAdvancedSecurityData.getData('username', USER_POOL_ID , CLIENT_ID) ` it returned `ecodedData` string. I passed it to my server from there I passed it as a parameter to IntiateAuth API, I am getting **AccountTakeOver High-risk** error. I don't know why it is coming like that and the **Device** column is still showing Unknown in Cognito Sign In event.

Comment: @Ardian Now my Sign In is passing without any risk, but Device column is still showing **Unknown** in Cognito Sign In event.

Comment: Hi @samba, probably you did not include IP address when initiateAuth (I used `AdminInitiateAuth`, though)? But anyway, Cognito has risk level calculation that we don't know its algorithm so it is totally Black box to predict the risk level.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have discontinued using Cognito because of some behavior I didn't understand, including that 'Unknown' thing. Also, the cost was so high for us with Adaptive Security enabled. :)

Comment: Hi @Ardian, Even after sending UserContextData it is not showing/identifying **Device name** that's why it showing 'Unknown' for that column. Is there anything I have to do from my end to see **Device name**.

Comment: @Ardian, In `AdminInitiateAuth` what are **ServerName** and **ServerPath** any example?. What are the **HTTP headers** we have to pass to this API?

Comment: unknown device name was one of Cognito's behavior I did not understand.

For ServerName, I used to put my domain name on it. ServerPath was my source of URL user logged in, in my case is /login